# Installing mongodb as service

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install `mongodb` as service on a machine running `Windows Server 2008R2`. I'm getting this message in the command prompt:

> The service is not responding to the control function. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.

I have tried either removing `--install` option from config file/adding this option to the execution script, using script like

> mongod --config mongod.config --service --reinstall

There is unresolved issue at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5115 describing the same problem.

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path for the config file, e.g. `mongod --config "C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.config" --install`?

Comment: @mnemosyn That helped!